# Problems in render method in Storybook

Tags: styled-components, storybook

I have this componnent

```js
import { Icons } from '.'
import { IconProps } from './icon.props'
import { normalize } from '../../utils/normalize'

const ROOT: ImageStyle = {
  resizeMode: 'contain'
}

export function Icon (props: IconProps): React.ReactElement {
  const { style: styleOverride, icon, containerStyle, width, color, fill } = props

  const SvgIcon = Icons[icon as keyof typeof Icons]

  const size = normalize(Number(width))

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
       <SvgIcon style={[ROOT, styleOverride]} width={size || normalize(15)} height={size || normalize(15)} stroke={color} fill={fill}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to see a story with this component I get the following error

```bash
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.

Check the render method of `Icon`.
```

In order to clarify something I followed this Stack post [link](https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/issues/472) to integrate styled-components to storybook.
Any ideas what could be happening?